# Are software library/framework recommendations/advices on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are software library/framework recommendations/advices on-topic here?

I have several "on hold" or "closed" questions on SO (and saw a ton of them) which essentially ask for recommendation for a library that designed to work on described platform/architecture/environment/language and perform desired actions or provide desired features.

Most of such type of question for 5 minutes of life ever got reasonable and strong answers before being closed.

While I am veteran SO user I have discovered  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com just today.

Comment: Related: [Is suggesting python libraries/solution a proper software recommendations?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2309/185) – but as a contra, take care of what kind of libraries you're talking about: [Would icon and font library questions be on topic?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185)

Comment: Thanks for interest! I have already read these articles. I have dug for half hour until decide ask clear specific question. They support my expectation that question about library recommendations are on-topic here but I afraid those "closed as off-topic" words.

Comment: I'd consider a library "software for programmers", and thus on-topic. Oh well, I [even have proof](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=library+answers%3A1)! Going to make this an answer, give me a few minutes...

Comment: Wow! Thanks for sharing useful example of embedded search query syntax! Now I found help under *Advanced Search Tips* link.

Comment: Glad you liked that! Encouraged me to give you one more example in my answer. It's a real powerful tool, our search engine – once you got the knack of using it :) When performing your next search, try out the "Advanced Search Tips" link at the top-right of that screen – much more to discover there :)

Comment: Old discussion about "programming tools" (including libraries): [Is it alright to ask for programming tools?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/8/60)

Comment: For reference, we currently have 288 questions using the [tag:library] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd consider a library "software for programmers", and thus on-topic. Doing a search on [library questions with answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=library+answers%3A1) turns out:

- 352 questions altogether
- only [6 of them got closed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=library+answers%3A1+closed%3Ayes): 3 for being "unclear"
- only 3 have being closed as off-topic: 1 not being about a library at all (rather asking for a how-to), 1 lacking all essentials from our quality guideline, and the remaining 1 being hard to read/understand

While not being "perfect proof" that library questions are on-topic, it at least shows they are "accepted" – which IMHO is pretty much the same.

Comment: Do I need to mark your answer as solution? I don't know what that mean for meta sites ((

Comment: Accepting means the same as on the main site – just up/downvotes are interpreted different ("agree/disagree"). Plus one doesn't gain rep here. So yes, I'd say so :)