# Can I ask for help to develop a solution in this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, etiquette

I asked [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24825/rest-client-for-firefox-with-projects-feature-equivalent-for-advanced-rest-cl) some time ago and I got no answers to it.
I was googling for some solution that fits my needs, but I didn't find anything.

Now, I decided to try to develop my own extension. Can I use this site to get help?

I mean, I will create a repository in Github (for example). Can I edit my question and put the link to it or is this spam? Maybe a comment?

I'm using my question as example, but I'd like to know it in a general way. Is there any guidance for these cases here in SoftwaRecs?

I found this [similar question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/is-offerring-to-write-a-program-for-someone-spam), but it's not the same case. In my example, the OP decides to develop a solution and is looking for help (collaborative or even paid). What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This entirely depends on the kind of help your asking for, naturally:

- it is OK to ask for [libraries, frameworks etc.](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2337/185)
- [asking for algorithms is not](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185)
- given the correct phrasing, you can [ask for programming tools](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/185)
- it's not OK to [ask for assets](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/185) (data, media, icons etc.)
- neither is [asking for manuals, howtos, tutorials, best approaches](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185)
- [asking for APIs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/185) *might* be OK or not, depends on
- looking for personnel is not fitting here either – for that there's [Carriers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Alright, I understood that look for personnel help is not allowed here. I was thinking about just a comment in my original question with something like: "Hey guys, I decide to create my own extension. Here is the link for my repo in Github". Is it allowed?

Comment: Afraid not, the way you put it. On this site, questions are expected to give specific requirements for a software looked for. If this part is missing, the question does not fit. If OTOH you're e.g. looking for a specific library, and the Github link helps pointing out details otherwise unclear, that should be OK. Plus, of course, if it's an answer and your extension fits all requirements and is ready to use, that's a complete other question again :)

Comment: Ok, it's all clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As soon as your tool meets the requirements given in your question, you [may](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) post it as an answer (don’t forget to [disclose your affiliation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)). You should not directly ask for help, but you may note that the project welcomes feature/pull requests, as this is relevant information, and it can be an advantage over other solutions.

If your tool is not yet meeting the requirements, I think there’s nothing wrong with posting a comment to your question, e.g.:

> As there doesn’t seem to exist a solution, I started a [project](http://example.org/) to develop it.

Such a comment (which is not really different from similar status updates, like "I’m currently trying out *tool X*" or "Found out about *tool Y*, will look into it") can be relevant information, e.g. because people that also need this solution might be interested in checking it out, or because others who would have started their own project to offer a solution to the question might not have to.

The question should not be edited to include the link, as the question post is not the right place to note what you ended up with. However, if you list tools you already tried and point out why they are not possible solutions, I think there’s nothing wrong with listing your own tool (again, with affiliation disclosure) if it meets some but not all of the features (i.e., it’s more than just an idea).